# How to save relations (many-to-many) between local data and an API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, many-to-many

I'm looking for a proper way to handle and store relations between data in my DB and data from a third party API. I use Laravel 5.

For example, I have a Project model (id, name). Also, I have an API which I can call from PHP and get back a JSON with Articles list.

I need to save a many-to-many relation with a junction table between Projects and Articles.
Because Articles data comes from API I do not have a local table with Articles so I can't use Eloquent to deal with relations.

My question is how to do it right.

I've thought of 2 possible solutions:

1.) Use some lib that can "map" an API as an Eloquent model. But I've only found abandoned projects. And overall this solution looks like overkill in such simple situation.

2.) Use query builder and manually handle this situation to save data about relations between Projects and Articles in the junction table.
But if I'll use this option it will be hard to deal with updates etc.

Comment: Presumably when you make the request you know which project the request belongs to?  If so, why not have a map between project and json response?  Do you know the structure of the Articles?

Comment: Articles in this example will have a pretty easy structure: only name and ID. And yes I know which project the request belongs to.

Comment: I'd say don't overcomplicate this. Just manually set `$model->related_id_from_api; $model->save()` and call it a day. Any solution will essentially overriding eloquent to make it work with API sources which is not a simple task.

Comment: @apokryfos It's a many-to-many relation with a junction table so $model->related_id is not an option.

Comment: You can create a model for the pivot table and extend [Pivot](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Pivot.php) in that case.